# map of function list and arguments: unpacking difficulty

Tags: python, dictionary, zip, reduce, iterable-unpacking

I have an assignment in a mooc where I have to code a function that returns the cumulative sum, cumulative product, max and min of an input list.
This part of the course was about functional programming, so I wanted to go all out on this, even though I can use other ways.
So I tried this:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import repeat
from functools import reduce
def reduce2(l):
    print(l)
    return reduce(*l)
def numbers(l):
    return tuple(map(reduce2, zip([sum, mul,min, max], repeat(l,4))))
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
numbers(l)
```

My problem is that it doesn't work. zip will pass only one object to reduce if I use it inside map, and unpacking the zip will yield the 4 tuple of (function and argument list l) so I defined reduce2 for this reason, I wanted to unpack the zip inside it but it did not work.
Python returns a TypeError: int' object is not iterable
I thought that I could use return reduce(l[0],l[1]) in reduce2, but there is still the same Error.
I don't understand the behavior of python here. 
If I merely use return reduce(l), it returns again a TypeError: reduce expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

What's happening here? How could I make it work? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, you are trying to execute code like this:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
reduce(sum, xs)
```

But `sum` takes an iterable and isn't really compatible with direct use via `reduce`. Instead, you need a function that takes 2 arguments and returns their sum -- a function analogous to `mul`. You can get that from `operator`:

```
from operator import mul, add
```

Then just change `sum` to `add` in your program.

BTW, functional programming has a variable naming convention that is really cool: `x` for one thing, and `xs` for a list of them. It's much better than the hard-to-read `l` variable name. Also it uses singular/plural to tell you whether you are dealing with a scalar value or a collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precision about naming conventions. I wasn't aware of that. Well done for add, actually sum is redundant with reduce, now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

[FMc answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40822407/6732794) correctly diagnoses the error in your code. I just want to add a couple alternatives to your `map` + `zip` approach.

For one, instead of defining a special version of `reduce`, you can use [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) instead of `map`, which is designed specifically for this purpose:

```
def numbers(xs): 
    return tuple(starmap(reduce, zip([add, mul, min, max], repeat(xs))))
```

However, even better would be to use the often ignored [variadic version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) of `map` instead of manually zipping the arguments:

```
def numbers(xs):
    return tuple(map(reduce, [add, mul, min, max], repeat(xs)))
```

It essentially does the `zip` + `starmap` for you. In terms of functional programming, this version of `map` is analogous to Haskell's [zipWith](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) function.

Comment: I knew starmap but didn't think of it, on the other hand, this version of map was unknown to me. I hope your answer get upvoted more. I will accept FMc's answer as he did answer first, but yours' deserves praise too.